# Why do python's os.stat and du and ls not agree on block size?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, python

While writing a simple function that computes the quantity of blocks consumed in a directory, I checked with du to see that I was getting the same answers.

Why do ls and du say this file occupies 16 blocks?

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

targetfile=/scratch/blob
rm -rf /scratch > /dev/null 2>&1
mkdir -p /scratch > /dev/null 2>&1
bs=$(dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/testvm-root 2> /dev/null | grep "Block size:")
bs=${bs/Block size:/}
bs=${bs// /}
echo blocksize=$bs
# create a file slightly too big for three blocks
dd if=/dev/zero of=$targetfile count=1 bs=$((bs*3+1)) > /dev/null 2>&1

echo "du says $(du $targetfile) units"
echo "du says $(du -b $targetfile) bytes:"
echo "ls says $(ls -s $targetfile) blocks"

echo "python says:"
python <(cat <<ENDMARKER
import os
import math
x = os.stat("$targetfile")
blocks=math.ceil(float(x.st_size)/float(x.st_blksize))
print("%d bytes st_blksize=%d, %d blocks " % (x.st_size,x.st_blksize,blocks))
print("blocksize=%d" % os.statvfs("$targetfile").f_bsize)
ENDMARKER
)
```

This is what I see:

```
blocksize=4096
du says 16      /scratch/blob units
du says 12289   /scratch/blob bytes:
ls says 16 /scratch/blob blocks
python says:
12289 bytes st_blksize=4096, 4 blocks 
blocksize=4096
```

I would expect ls -s to say 4 blocks just like du -B 4096 does.

Comment: possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage

Comment: That's a good read but doesn't exactly answer my question.  Upon reading the du man page again, I see that by default it reports usage in units of 512-byte blocks.  I don't understand why, but at least I get the numbers I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `du` and `ls` default to the block size of 1024 bytes when calculating the number of blocks. Since your filesystem is configured with 4K blocks, and the file uses 4 such 4K blocks, both of them report 16 1K-blocks used.

[du(1) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) mentions this fact in the end of its Description section, whereas [ls(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) does not state it directly. However, both programs are a part of GNU coreutils suite and support the same -B/--block-size options so I guess they are likely to rely on the same implementation.

If you want to get the real number of blocks used, you have to provide filesystem blocksize both to `ls` and `du`.

Comment: Using --block-size=4096 for du and ls does show what I would expect.